# Using Using python 3.6.4 32bit, I am getting the thank you in this code executing before the break. How do I get it to execute after instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using **python 3.6.4 32bit**, I am getting the thank you in this code executing  before the break. How do I get it to execute after instead?

```
name = ''
while True:
    print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    if name == 'your name':
        break
    print('thank you!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to say thank you after the user input 'your name' ?

```
name = ''
while True:
    print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    if name == 'your name':
        break
print('thank you!')
```

what `break` does is exit from your loop.

Comment: I am getting the thank you executing before I enter 'your name' , how do I correct the script to execute the 'thank you!' after 'your name' is input and not before ...?

Answer (score 0):

```
name = ''
while True:
    print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    if name == 'your name':
        print('thank you!')
        break
```

This code prints 'thank you' if name == 'your name' else does nothing.